# Copy File from One Specific Sub directory to Other Specific Sub directories

Tags: bash, find, xargs, cp

I couldn't find a great answer to this question, so bear with me as this is a pretty simple question.

I have files inside of specific directories, and need to copy them into other specific directories using cron at a specified time. Like this:

```
/var/www/html/files/client1/1.txt
/var/www/html/files/client2/1.txt
/var/www.html/files/client3/1.txt 
... and so on for many directories
```

Each file "1.txt" is specific to a client, so must be copied specifically to a destination folder.

```
/var/www/html/desintation/client1/1.txt
/var/www/html/desintation/client2/1.txt
/var/www/html/desintation/client3/1.txt
...and so on...
```

If you just want to point me in a place to start, that's cool with me. But my question is basically, how can I ensure that client1 files always end up in the client1 destination? Because it seems to me like with wildcarding I am unable to account for that and there is a chance a file will end up in the wrong directory.

Comment: I would be inclined to so something simple if you have nothing but client directories under `files`. You can simply do `cp -ua /var/www/html/files/* /var/www/html/desintation`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in your /var/www/html/files directory, maybe consider something like the following:

```
find . -name 1.txt -exec cp \"{}\" \"/var/www/html/destination/{}\" \;
```

The "find . -name 1.txt" bit will find a list of relative paths to files named 1.txt from the current directory:

```
./client1/1.txt
./client2/1.txt
./client3/1.txt
```

The "exec" portion will use that to execute commands like:

```
cp "./client1/1.txt" "/var/www/html/destination/./client1/1.txt"
cp "./client2/1.txt" "/var/www/html/destination/./client2/1.txt"
cp "./client3/1.txt" "/var/www/html/destination/./client3/1.txt"
```

You can experiment by adding an echo to see what commands it would output if you actually ran it:

```
find . -name 1.txt -exec echo cp \"{}\" \"/var/www/html/destination/{}\" \;
```